# Is automatic Wake On LAN possible with DD-WRT?

Tags: networking, dd-wrt, wake-on-lan, wake-on-demand

I might be thinking the wrong way to solve this problem. If there's a better way, than tell me. I want to be able to allow my home server to sleep when it's unused, but to automatically wake up when it's accessed. My household doesn't follow a set schedule due to people working different shifts, so I can't schedule an optimal sleep/wake cycle for the server

There is a WOL daemon for DD-WRT that sends out wake up packets on a scheduled interval, but this is not what I want. I would like for my home server to automatically sleep, but also automatically wake up when it is accessed.

I do not want to use any kind of utility to explicitly send a wake-up packet. I have the server mapped to static IP address. I would like to know if any solution exists that would automatically send wake up packets if the static IP was considered unreachable due to the the computer being in a power-savings mode.

Answer (score 3):

This guy might be doing what you're asking:

http://gaddgets.blogspot.com/2007/02/auto-wol-on-dd-wrt-on-linksys-wrt54gl.html

> I thought I would try to set it up to
>   wake up the computer on a Port 80
>   (http) access if it was in "sleep"
>   mode. ... I would parse the syslog to
>   detect port 80 activity. ... There is
>   a lag now, when the computer is asleep
>   to access a page on the computer.
>   However I find that in most cases, the
>   browser timeout is long enough to wake
>   the computer up and deliver the
>   webpage.

The script he wrote is at that link.  If you're accessing on another port, change the port I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

- The **DD-WRT Wiki** has this -- [Wake-on-LAN (tutorial)](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL).
- **Lifehacker**: [**Access Your Computer Anytime and Save Energy with Wake-on-LAN**](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan)
- And, **CodingHorror** posting -- [**Remotely Waking Up Your PC**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000790.html)

---

I found this [for WinXP on the dd-wrt forums](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=248689),

> if I put my box into hibernation, I wasn't able to wake it up anymore. The solution is very simple: go to Device manager (or run `devmgmt.msc`), select your ethernet adapter, double click on it and go to **Power management** tab. Check both **Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby** and **Only allow management stations to bring computer out of standby**.
>   If you check only the former, even simple ping wil wake you computer up!

If that does not work,
you will probably have to keep a desktop-icon to a batch/shell script for the wakeup.

Comment: I read the DD-WRT wiki before asking the question. My understanding was that you had to explicitly send the wake up. I would like the wake up to happen automatically. I have clarified the question with my requirements.